# Bad tags always triumph! Oh? All right, we'll call it a [.*draw.*]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request

I think a number of similar generic drawing-related tags should go away. These tags don't add any information that can't already be covered by a language-specific GUI/painting/graphics tag. The questions in the tag are spread over a variety of languages, and none of the questions I have seen with these tags can really be answered by somebody who isn't knowledgeable in the specific language (i.e. no compelling reason for general "drawing rectangles" or similar categories).

There is a choice to be made here which I would like to open a discussion on. The [drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawing) tag is very general, and the purpose of this request is to make these tags more specific. On the other hand, it is more heavily used than the other tags listed here (x3459) and it could be a reasonable subtopic tag. I am on the fence: If we support this tag then it is a viable synonym for many of the tags below. If we do not support this tag then the recommended action for the tags below is burninate/blacklist/retag as indicated. I will present recommended actions for both cases.

Tags that should go away for the reasons mentioned above (already covered by language-specific drawing framework tags) follow:

- [redraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redraw) **: 228**

  - Widely spread across *c#(18), javascript(18), java(14), objective-c(9), c++(8), css(7), html(6)*
  - No language trend in top-voted questions.
  - All observed questions deal with general redrawing of things. Many APIs have a `redraw()` method/function, but not specific enough to warrant a specialized **-redraw* tag for that particular language/api.
  - **Recommend** (if not *drawing*): Blacklist due to constant misuse.
  - **Recommend** (if *drawing*): Merge into *drawing*.
- [drawtext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawtext) **: 131**

  - Some relevance to Java's `Canvas.drawText`. I believe nothing is gained from this method-specific tag, all questions can be subsumed into *android* + *drawing* or *graphics*.
  - Other language tags in use: *c++(17), java(9),delphi(6), python(5), c#(3)*
  - Side Note: Investigation of this tag uncovered heavy inappropriate usage (Android Graphics API) of *canvas* as per its wiki description (HTML5). Many of these should be moved to *android-canvas*.
  - **Recommend** (if not *drawing*): In questions tagged *android*, retag *drawtext* as *android-canvas*, then burninate.
  - **Recommend** (if *drawing*): In questions tagged *android*, add *android-canvas*. Merge into *drawing*.
- [drawrectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawrectangle) **: 56**

  - Biased to *c#(17)*, widely spread over *java(7), vb.net(4), javascript(3), asp.net(2)*
  - There is a Windows Forms `DrawRectangle` method; [8 questions with this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdrawrectangle%5D%20%22drawrectangle%22%20is:question) relate to this method. This does not add any useful information beyond what a language-specific graphics system tag or *drawing* adds.
  - **Recommend** (if not *drawing*): Manual removal. For Windows Forms related questions, replace with either *system.drawing* or *gdi+*. For all other questions, remove tag. Blacklist due to heavy misuse.
  - **Recommend** (if *drawing*): Manual removal. For Windows Forms related questions, replace with *drawing*. For all other questions, remove tag. Blacklist due to heavy misuse.
  - Note: shog9 updated the tag wiki in response to this question with info about the Windows Forms method. I think this is a good step but not sufficient to justify the tag.
- [ownerdrawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ownerdrawn) **: 64**

  - "Owner-drawn" is a general concept. In all APIs where owner-drawn components exist, there are always better API-specific tags for the component type being drawn (or drawn on), such as the existing *custom-controls* tag for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734419/changing-createparams-dynamically), or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467277/why-is-there-a-separate-message-for-wm-erasebkgnd) which should be tagged *winapi* + *gdi* instead.
  - In many cases the question involves an owner-drawn object but is actually about something else, or is [misused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220100/how-do-i-enable-double-buffering-of-a-control-using-c-sharp-window-forms).
  - **Recommend:** Burninate, possibly blacklist after monitoring.
- [ownerdraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ownerdraw) **: 57**

  - **Recommend:** Burninate; same rationale as *ownerdrawn* (should have been a synonym to begin with.)
- [drawing2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawing2d) **: 52**

  - There is a .NET package named `Drawing2D` but only [3 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdrawing2d%5D%20%22drawing2d%22%20is:question) specifically mention it. In all other cases questions are simply about drawing things in 2D, which can just as effectively be covered under *drawing* or a more specific tag.
  - **Recommend** (if not *drawing*): Blacklist due to constant misuse.
  - **Recommend** (if *drawing*): Merge into *drawing* tag.
- [drawbitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawbitmap) **: 44**

  - Android's `Canvas.DrawBitmap` is frequently tagged with this, but this tag adds no information beyond *android-canvas*. Majority of *drawbitmap* tags are used in Android `Canvas` context.
  - **Recommend** (if not *drawing*): Manual removal of tag from questions not also tagged *android*. Merge into *android-canvas*.
  - **Recommend** (if *drawing*): For questions tagged android, add *android-canvas*. Merge into *drawing*.
- [drawingcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawingcontext) **: 33**

  - WPF has a `DrawingContext`, but *drawingcontext* adds no information that *wpf* does not cover.
  - **Recommend:** Manually ensure that all questions tagged *drawingcontext* and either *c#* or *wpf* are tagged with both *c#* *and* *wpf*. Burninate.
- [custom-draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-draw) **: 28**

  - This tag is used for general custom drawing. These questions are better served by using API-specific tags.
  - Evenly spread across: *c#(6), c++(5), delphi(3), java(2)*
  - **Recommend** (if not *drawing*): Blacklist due to constant misuse.
  - **Recommend** (if *drawing*): Merge into *drawing*.

Comment: The peasants, all the people, *and* the thatched-roof cottages...I admire your dedication to burnination!

Comment: Yes please. Just but them under a [tag:drawing] tag or [tag:graphics] tag, or something like that

Comment: 68 tags can be removed in a very brief period of time, and then the tag will get auto-burninated. The last question was active 5 days ago in [drawrectangle], so I don't see why this requires mod intervention (it doesn't seem like it's likely to pop back up if the tag is cleaned and deleted). Any specific reason these can't be done by hand?

Comment: @jmac Any specific reason these can't be burninated not-by-hand? There are 12 tags in my list. You work on half and I'll work on the other half. Any preferences?

Comment: I'll go bottom up.

Comment: All right then; sounds like a plan.

Comment: 68 is fine, but that is actually one of the less populated ones. Altogether it's over 860 questions. I will at least knock off the smaller ones first, and cross them off, starting with drawingbrush.

Comment: It would also seem that drawingbrush at least is used for two separate tags: xaml and silverlight. It seems to be an object type.

Comment: @jmac In that case, perhaps the [tag:drawingbrush] wiki should be updated, and questions not related to that object be untagged. I am not familiar enough with xaml or silverlight to be 100% confident, or to judge if it is worth a dedicated tag.

Comment: @Jason, then it would seem that prior to asking to burninate, it may be wiser to look in to the tags you are advocating the elimination of a bit more closely? For now I will roll back my edits.

Comment: @jmac Would normally agree except there are only 33 questions with that tag and it had no description in the wiki. To me this is strong evidence that it is not worthwhile. Also in general I do not support tags related to specific objects/functions in an API.

Comment: Silverlight uses XAML, @jmac. They are not entirely distinct contexts.

Comment: I strongly disagree. It looks like [drawingbrush] was being added to questions [by a Microsoft Employee](http://stackoverflow.com/users/265706/jerry-nixon-msft). You may want to ping him and ask him to update the wiki, or offer to do it for him. In the meantime, I am rolling stuff back to put it back in

Comment: @jmac I will do that re: [tag:drawingbrush] and remove that tag from this post for now.

Comment: @Jason, can I suggest adding a bit more info on each of these tags, how they are misused, and how you want them to be handled? Just burninating them all seems to be a bit problematic, so it may be worthwhile to figure out which ones can be auto-burninated, which ones should be manually retagged, and what the criteria are to determine how to retag them?

Comment: @jmac That's a reasonable request; I will work on that now.

Comment: @jmac In coming up with recommended actions for these tags; I am faced with deciding whether or not [tag:drawing] should be used more heavily (it serves as a good replacement for all the tags I've checked so far) or if it is too general a tag. Basically, recommending that tags be merged into *drawing* vs. burninate/blacklist and retags in specific situations (e.g. *redraw* could be either changed to *drawing* or blacklisted; *drawtext* with *android* can be replaced manually with *android-canvas* and otherwise burninated, or *drawtext* could be generally merged with *drawing*). Any insight?

Comment: I prefer specificity, Jason.

Comment: @Jason, if the use of each individual tags is distinct and serves to better categorize those questions, it is better to keep them individual as Shog said. Merging/synonymizing tags is the better choice if two distinct tags are being used to talk about the same thing. If people are using [js] and [javascript] to describe javascript questions, then they should be merged, but just because [phantomjs] and [casperjs] and [jquery] could all be combined as [jslibraries] doesn't mean they should be (you lose info)

Comment: @jmac Research complete; updated. Re: *drawing*, presenting recommendations for both options.

Comment: @jmac That's good advice. The problem is, the more I dig, the deeper I get into a rabbit hole that I wasn't prepared to get in to (e.g. the discovery of misused *canvas*; tons of .net vs c# w/ wpf ambiguity, etc.). I know how I get with these types of things, and I'm afraid that if I push it, it will turn into a general push to get rid of over-specified dubious method/namespace/constant tags, which I don't have the time or motivation for right now. I'll think about it tonight and see if I can reorganize without getting sucked in too deep. For now; I'll let this marinate a little.

Comment: @Jason, yeah, the tags are a real nightmare once you jump in. Can I suggest perhaps breaking it down in to far more bitesize chunks? So start with one tag, with a clear method of cleaning it up, rally a few users to help you out, and when it's done move on to the next. It will never be perfect, but you can at least make small corners tidy, and then ask for mods with help on the rest (like was done when the [google] tag was blacklisted).

Comment: I'm gonna second that: this should probably be 9 separate discussions. At this point I don't know if folks are supporting the destruction of all of these, of just drawrectange, or of a careful cleanup effort.

Comment: I agree (I came to the same conclusion even before jmac's last comment); I won't have much time for SO today but already have a more step-by-step process planned. Also, once this is all over, depending on community reaction, I'd like to go on a mission of generally cleaning up method/namespace/constant tags (or at least ones that are frequently misused due to ambiguous names, like Ruby on Rail's `scope` vs. general questions about scope in [tag:scope]).

Comment: To do this properly, I think a prerequisite is that [tag:canvas] and [tag:drawing] will need to be cleaned up and clarified or removed first. I am going to open discussions on those two tags before proceeding with any of the tags listed in this post.

Comment: Ownerdrawn is useful, e.g. search for [winForms][Ownerdrawn]

Comment: SO has way too many tags. eliminate them all.  News: google exists

Answer (score 17):

Some of these are method / namespace / constant names in certain contexts. For instance,

- [DrawRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536003(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Drawing2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [DrawingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.drawtext(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Please use discretion when removing these tags:** they may actually describe some aspect of the question being asked. The Related Tags sidebar is a very useful tool for determining what context may apply when evaluating such tags.

Comment: I'm adding them back as we speak. Made the assumption the request was based on stronger footing than it was, and I didn't have the technical acumen to judge either way until I had done a dozen and realized it seemed a bit off.

Comment: Yes; I have been looking out for this type of usage. So far I have found none for [tag:drawrectangle]. Also I generally do not support tags for methods/namespaces/constants, especially with low usage counts.

Comment: @jmac Every [tag:drawrectangle] I have removed has been legitimate. I will proceed through the rest of the tags with care and update the request accordingly on the chance that I find anything that seems worth keeping.

Comment: It's definitely been misused a lot, @Jason. I've updated the tag wiki to hopefully help with this.

Comment: Readers - please note this answer was posted before I added detailed per-tag information to post (just now).

Comment: What usefull are these tags, e.g how many peole are experts in DrawRectangle and therefore filter the questions to they can answer questions on DrawRectangle?

Comment: No idea, @Ian. Tag has one follower though... Frankly, I'm more concerned about tags like [tag:drawingcontext], which strikes me as the sort of thing where one might actually hold onto some rare knowledge after a while.

Comment: @Shog9 In general that's a valid concern, of course. Re: [tag:drawingcontext] specifically, though: All the questions in [tag:drawingcontext] fall in to one of two categories: WPF's `DrawingContext`, or questions about whatever generic "drawing context" concept applies to a given API. There's not really any API-agnostic bit of knowledge that the latter could contain. The former is legitimate (if you consider API object tags legitimate), but could just as well be part of [tag:wpf]; same knowledge base, so there's not much benefit to offset the cost of the frequent misapplication.

Comment: I do consider API tags legit, @Jason. Yes, you can always find a bigger tag to lump stuff into - but we don't just slap [tag:programming] on every question and call it a day, 'cause then we lose the ability to refine your browsing, monitoring and searching to just those areas where you have a specific interest. Maybe I've worked with WPF graphics extensively but don't care about its brain-damaged web service features? Who knows... Point is, whether or not THESE tags are well-used, API-specific tags can be and often are.