# Synonymize or merge [draw] and [drawing]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

The tags [draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/draw) (2k questions) and [drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawing) (4k) seem to mean the same thing, and I think plural versions of tags are useless.

---

The tag excerpt for [drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawing) says:

> Issues around forms and graphics being drawn onto a computer screen, windowing system or device

And the one for [draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/draw) says:

> A tag for questions about methods of displaying graphical data or images.

---

Maybe they should be synonymized / merged ?

Some discussion was [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250913/burninate-blacklist-merge-many-drawing-related-tags), but not much happened, and it does not address these tags.

Answer (score 2):

Even if a clear line was to be drawn, we'd have to sort through 6,125 questions to tag correctly. Then most users will still tag incorrectly because few read even the wiki except.

I fully support a merge/burnination.

Comment: Please note, burnination has NOT occured.  Image is incorrect.