# We're not in [canvas] anymore

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

As I already commented in the comments on [Can these questions with changed tags be returned to their original tagging?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326743/is-this-badge-fraud-and-if-yes-can-it-be-corrected), I don't see the tag [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) being useful.

The criteria:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   No, definitely not. As [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/canvas/info) info describes, a canvas is:

   - A HTML5 element
   - A Java-canvas in Android
   - Part of classic Windows (Win32/Win64) GDI subsystem
   - A component of Windows Presentation Foundation
   - A component in Python Tkinter

   Those topics have *nothing* in common, so you can not become an expert in `canvas`. (Being able to be an expert in a topic was a requirement for something, don't remember what it was).
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Yes
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   Well, it adds the information that the question is about one of the in **1.** stated topics. We also have the [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas), so [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) provides no additional information if [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) is also added.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   As stated in **1.**, definitely not.

The short-info says:

> Canvas is a drawing element introduced to web development with HTML5. For Android or WPF, use android-canvas or WPF-controls.

However, **if** the [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) is only meant to be used as tag for **HTML5 canvas** question, then it is merely a synonym to [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas). I don't see a reason to keep both, [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) and [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas), I'd prefer to burninate the ambiguous [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) tag and keep the [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) tag.

Opinions?

Comment: Thanks for posting this request and allowing the community to weigh in! Please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow (please think twice before doing tag-only mass edits, as they can be counter-productive); once the community reaches a consensus, burnination can proceed. For more info, see [What is the process for burninating tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070).

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253790/html5-canvas-tag-should-be-a-synonym-of-the-canvas-tag/290374#290374

Comment: partly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250913/burninate-blacklist-merge-many-drawing-related-tags

Comment: Eh? [Canvas *alone* is definitively not on topic for the site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas). It needs a predicated to be on topic.

Comment: No, it should not be removed. Perhaps synonymized, but not removed. There is a difference between uses of the html tag canvas and the graphical design issues associated with using the canvas in general. I don't think the distinction is problematic. What problem would be solved by removing this tag?

Comment: Tangentially related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326743/2693146 (a gold badge holder conspicuously removed some html-canvas tags in questions) If [tag:canvas] was burninated, that would've covered a couple of the questions affected.

Comment: Idea: would making this synonymous with [tag:html-canvas] work, since that's the majority of the questions (~16k out of ~22k are tagged with [tag:html], [tag:html5], and/or [tag:javascript])?

Comment: And title idea: Let's clean off this [canvas]! :-)

Comment: Same problem as [this guy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326746/request-for-comments-on-burnination): misinterpreting the 4th rule as a justification for burninating tags that have overlapping meanings. The tag system has full support for multiple tags, so we don't need abominations like [html5-canvas], [wpf-canvas], [android-java-canvas], [python-tkinter-canvas], ...

Comment: Also related [Confused with the definitions of canvas and html5-canvas](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300003)

Comment: @Braiam what about [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C)? Or [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby)?

Comment: @AndrasDeak what about them?

Comment: @Braiam I understood your above message to say "Canvas is a thing on which we paint, so it's not about programming, see wikipedia". I showed two examples (a letter and a gemstone) that also don't have anything to do with programming. Context makes the difference, and in a programming context `canvas` has a meaning. A *broad* meaning, mind you, but definitely not "*definitively not on topic for the site*". Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @AndrasDeak the thing is, that in tagging, everything should be obvious even without tags accompanying them. [I refer you to the pig question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617817/pig-epidemic-java-array), which is why I'm a firm believer that the naming should be unambiguous even for the untrained eye.

Comment: @Braiam I'm not saying that [canvas] should be kept at all cost, as I said, I agree that it's broad. But it has a clearly programming-related meaning as well. It could be a broad/bad tag, but it shouldn't be excluded on the basis of paintings.

Comment: Yes.  I've a feeling we're not in [canvas] anymore.

Comment: [Evidence for the use of canvas in non-HTML contexts.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326856/734069) I think such questions need to be retagged to be more specific to their APIs.

Comment: So...you think we shouldn't have a tag for Apache Pig because someone might get confused and ask a question about pigs? That's just arrant nonsense. All will be lost if jewelers catch wind of this site and start asking questions about creating ruby settings. Guess we'll need [ruby-language] or some such noise. Just say no. Don't blame bad questions on the tags, blame them on the people who ask them. Like people that are too stupid to see that this is a *programming* Q&A site. We don't need to put [-programming] in all of our tags.

Comment: "Please use [tag:android-canvas] for android canvases" - tag wiki

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326987/327083 - `canvas` is useful in the same way that `button`, `listview`, and `combobox` are useful.  They are ubiquitous elements that transcend languages but retain a nearly identical behaviour.  An associated, separate, language tag provides the necessary context (if needed).  Related : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300571/327083

Comment: I'd argue if you're an expert on a topic you should be able to subscribe to a tag and answer most of its questions. Almost no one could do that for `canvas` or `button`. Otherwise what would be the point of subscribing to a tag? Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326855/request-to-merge-and-or-blacklist-canvas-tag